# Finding the joint distribution and covariance matrix of a function.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> **Question:** Let X and Y be two continuous random variables with joint probability density function
>
> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} & \text{if} \ \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert \le 1 & \\
> 0 :\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> Find the joint probability density function of $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$
>   And then find the covariance matrix of the distribution

**My attempt:**

For the first part I think I have managed to work out the correct answer.I got,

$$f(u,v)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{4} & \text{if} \ \lvert u \rvert \le 1,  \lvert v \rvert \le 1 & \\
0 :\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

For the covariance part, I got $Cov(U,V)=0$ and $Var(U) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $Var(V) = \frac{1}{3}$ However this doesn't feel right.

Is this correct? Also can we tell from the covariance matrix, whether or not this is independent?

Comment: "However this doesn't feel right." Why?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't but I just didn't expect this answer

Comment: Is this the correct answer?

Comment: You're not quite there yet.  Look at the range of values for $u$ and $v$.  How can the area be 1 and the density be a constant $1/4$?  Another way of looking at it is "Why aren't there any negative values in your current range for $v$" ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is my updated answer correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.  You might want to work it backwards to convince yourself.  Take a large random sample of $u$ and $v$ and see what you get for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you! The most difficult part of this question was finding the range of u and v, do you have any advice for questions similar to this?